# What are the possible finite non-solvable quotients of one relator groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a one-relator group with some finite non-solvable quotient, that does not have all large alternating groups as finite quotients?

Comment: The Baumslag- Solitar groups are examples of one-relator groups with only solvable finite quotients. The groups

Comment: G = < a,b | aa=bbb> and G = <a,b,c,d | abcd = dcba> have the alternating groups Alt(n) as quotients for all sufficiently large n. Is there something 'in between'?

Comment: Moshe: I think it's only true for Baumslag-Solitar $BS(m,n)$ with $m,n$ coprime.

Comment: Correct. If the powers are both divisible by p, say p>2, then you can take b to be of order p and the relation is trivially satisfied, so you can get pretty much anything as a quotient.

Comment: My impression is that these kind of questions are wide open.  Indeed, I think that every known 1-relator group either: (i) has every finite quotient metabelian; or (ii) is large (in the sense of Pride).  You might like to look at the following paper of Jack Button: 'Largeness of LERF and 1-relator groups', Groups Geom. Dyn. 4 (2010), 709–738.

Comment: I'm corresponding with Button already. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying the case aab=bba, which has some non-solvable quotients, but it does not seem to be known if it has all Alt(n) as quotients.